# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Is there any way to condense the list (only use the preposition once)?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

I am interested in knowing if this sentence is grammatically correct and if there is a way of preventing the repetition of “through” in the list.

> Throughout the play, numerous characters evoke this central theme in their own unique way, such as Hamlet through his madness, Claudius through his ‘murder most foul,’ Polonius through his hypocrisy, Ophelia through her impurity, and Gertrude through her incestuous behavior.

Comment: Looks correct to me.  And I don't find the repetition of "through" to be a problem -- it kind of ties things together.

Comment: Looks okay, as the repetition is deliberate. Start with a different pattern if you like: Hamlet's madness, Claudius' murder ...  But I do object to sweet Ophelia labeled impure when it's Hamlet who's the accusatory bastard. Okay, his mom did recycle the funeral feast to cater her nuptials.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct. And to make it short, you can remove a few repeated and unhelpful words:

> Throughout the play, characters evoke the central theme in their own ways, Hamlet through his madness, Claudis his ‘murder most foul’, Polonius his hypocrisy, Ophelia her impurity, and Gertrude her incests.

You can also sharpen it up by using proper names instead of common names. But this would depend on your prior sentences. Perhaps you don't need those prior sentences explaining what the play is and what the central themes are.

> Throughout *Hamlet*, characters evoke themes of despair and revenge in their own ways, Hamlet through his madness, Claudis his ‘murder most foul’, Polonius his hypocrisy, Ophelia her impurity, and Gertrude her incests.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can often omit repeated elements when their meaning is clear. In a case such as this, it is common to replace them with commas:

> Throughout the play, numerous characters evoke this central theme in their own unique way, such as Hamlet through his madness, Claudius, his ‘murder most foul,’ Polonius, his hypocrisy, Ophelia, her impurity, and Gertrude, her incestuous behavior.

The profusion of commas is a bit confusing, so we can use semicolons to separate the listed items:

> Throughout the play, numerous characters evoke this central theme in their own unique way, such as Hamlet through his madness; Claudius, his ‘murder most foul’; Polonius, his hypocrisy; Ophelia, her impurity; and Gertrude, her incestuous behavior.

Some people simply omit the repeated elements without using commas:

> Throughout the play, numerous characters evoke this central theme in their own unique way, such as Hamlet through his madness, Claudius his ‘murder most foul,’ Polonius his hypocrisy, Ophelia her impurity, and Gertrude her incestuous behavior.

That being said, I find nothing wrong with the original version and would probably prefer it over the shorter versions.